# I need a formula for calculating the CR for a custom monster

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, homebrew

I need a math formula for calculating CR for a monster that I am creating.
Nothing too detailed just enough to give a fair fight to my players. Or at least leave one person alive.

Comment: The rules for assigning CR are in the books. I think in the DMG.

Comment: I've posted an answer on where you can find the rules for calculating a monster's CR. They're in one of the core rule books as Erik pointed out. It's not likely the answer you're looking for but we're unable to reproduce the text here as that would violate copyright laws. We would also rather teach you to fish than simply give you the fish. If there's anything in particular about these rules that gives you trouble, please feel free to ask another question explaining what parts you're struggling with and how you've tried to solve the problem yourself and we should be able to help from there.

Comment: See [this meta about "read the book to me" questions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/what-do-we-do-with-read-the-book-to-me-questions) for more detail on why your question was put on hold.  If you're asking where you can find the rules for this, you should make that clear and then we can re-open the Q.  If you're asking specifically for the rules on *how* to do this, we can't answer that type of question.

Comment: As Monkey as stated this is within the DMG. But it all depends on how many PC's you have and what level they are. For example, 1 PC at Level 1 would find anything with 25XP easy, 50XP would be medium, 75XP would be hard and 100XP would be deadly. This also changes on how many monsters/creatures you are up against because more a lower levesl COULD be more difficult than one creature at a higher level.

Comment: @Inhandable I don't think any of that's germane: creatures have a CR independent of party composition or encounter details. Those factors you mention go into *encounter* building, as described on DMG pp.81-85.

Comment: @nitsua60 Once you know the XP level that the players can handle , you can then gauge the CR level of the monster/creature that you need to create. By the sounds of the question, the person asking has a creature in mind that he is creating, but doesn't know how powerful to make it. So he needs a way to work out how strong/powerful it could be?

Comment: This is a simple question and deserves a simple answer: give them the pg no. from the relevant gamebook and be done with it. This is not appropriate for meta discussion nor should it be brought up in this case.

Answer (score 10):

Steps for how to calculate a monster's CR can be found on page 274 through to 279 of the DMG.